# why can't i set window.onload in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload

I have the following function, which works fine in Firefox, but will do nothing in IE8

```
function print(url) {
    var w = window.open(url);
    w.onload = function() {
        w.print();
    };
}
```

I want to open a webpage and immediately open the print dialogue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the hand on the page at `url`, place the call there.
In the HTML, at the end of the BODY tag.
Add a SCRIPT tag with your call

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    window.print();
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't handle the `load` event of window objects outside the current window because it doesn't work in all browsers. You need to handle the `load` event using a script in the document loaded into the new window. Your handler could either call `window.print()` itself, or, if you need to keep the functionality within the original window, it could make a call to the original window using the `window.opener` property or set a flag that script in the original window can poll.